# Infer Class/Instance type from constructor function

Tags: typescript

How would you infer either the class type or the instance type from a constructor function?

EDIT: I am given the prototype only, and want to get back the class type. See decorator example.

```js
Class User {}

// The following makes me really sad
User.prototype/* Object */.constructor/* Function */
```

Example with property decorator:

```js
// My code
// I cannot get class/instance type from T...
const Prop = <T>({ constructor }: T) => {}

// My user's code
class User {
  @Prop
  photos
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try `InstanceType`:

```js
type UserInstance = InstanceType<User>
```

Comment: Hey ! I was not clear about this, the User class is user's code, not my own...
Thanks for the answer anyway !